# UnicodeEncodeError: ascii when wishing to use unicode

Tags: macos, unicode, utf-8, python-3.x

I'm trying something like this:

```
outFile = open("file.txt", "wt",encoding='utf-8')
outFile.write(str(sentence))
outFile.close()
```

and getting the error:

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '/x4e'.

why is an ascii encoder being used?

Am I right in saying that my string (str(sentence)) is in unicode? Then why is it not simply encoded as utf-8 when writen to file? This code gives no exception when run on ubuntu and windows, with the exception occuring on mac os x.

Seems to me that ascii is being used by default somewhere on my mac even though i explicitly state the use of utf-8

Please help,

Barry

Answer (score 0):

`str()` returns a string yes. And a str will be encoded when written, yes.
I'm not entirely sure why the ascii encoding is being used (it is the default encoding in Python 2, but not in Python 3), but I'm even less sure why you do `str(sentence)`. If you want to decode bytes you don' use `str()` you use `.decode()`. So start with removing the `str()` call.

You don't give a full traceback, but I'm guessing that it's the `str(sentence)` that gives the error.